# SourceTree : Where are Created Tasks Located in Pull request comments

Tags: sourcetree

I wish to see where are my tasks located when I do a create task in SourceTree in Pull request comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bitbucket then you will see your tasks there only -

> You can keep track of all open and resolved tasks with a consolidated list available from the top of a pull request.

[image]

Refrence - https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/09/16/introducing-pull-request-tasks/

PS: If you are on some other tool, there should be similar options.

Comment: Thanks.  Perfect 

Answer (score 1):

**The quickest way**

1. Open the pull request.
2. Press **shift + T**